# Is it possible to re-skin activeadmin to work with JQuery-Mobile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, activeadmin

I've got an app that's using JQueryMobile and it's using the awesome ActiveAdmin extensively as well. While I love the ease and simplicity of the ActiveAdmin interface, I'd really like consistency with the rest of my app.

Is it possible (i.e. using standard ActiveAdmin and not modifying its sources) to re-skin ActiveAdmin to use the JQuery-Mobile look and feel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very possible to reskin ActiveAdmin, though it would be a bit of a job to do, and there would likely be quite a number of things that can't perfectly be built to match a mobile presentation, especially if you don't want to get into overriding markup rendering.

You can always simply start adding styles of your own to the active_admin.css file that is generated for you. If you'd like to start without any of ActiveAdmin's styles at all, you can comment out the two sass imports in that css file:

```
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";
```

Or at least just the base file. It may be intriguing to you in itself, or informative about the organization of the markup, to view your current admin pages without the base css, or with css turned off in your browser altogether. From that vantage point, you could begin to think through how the bare markup could be restyled to match a mobile presentation.

Comment: OK. I found it in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` (and `javascript`) and I'll experiment a bit.

Comment: Actually, it would take more than simply adding JQM javascript and css files — how do I add the JQM page wrappers? Is there an accessible layout file for ActiveAdmin pages?

Comment: ActiveAdmin's layouts and views are all written in Arbre (https://github.com/gregbell/arbre) and are generally difficult to adjust, even if you're only looking for simple adjustments. As you can see from the main layout file in AA's app/views/layouts directory, it calls a view factory instead of carrying out the task in the template file: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/views/layouts/active_admin.html.arb

Comment: Changing the layout can certainly be done but the complexity rises as it involves doing a lot of overriding or writing your own ruby modules. The view factory pattern may in fact be simpler than it appears at first glance, but there is definitely a learning curve, and its a significant time investment in order to adjust the layouts they way you discuss above.

In short, it doesn't look like the rewrapping AA in JQM markup can be done without significant investment.

Comment: Thanks, @a-moose. This gives me the rest of the information that I was looking for: basically, while it is (technically) possible to do so, it's likely to be a significant time investment (and therefore probably defeats the purpose of the super-cool, automatic admin panel that is ActiveAdmin. If I'm considering this, I may as well just write the darned things from scratch.